# Checking the probability of an object

Tags: java

I am working on a simulation of trains leaving cities in the US on a random basis. How it works is every second (tick) I need to set the probablity of each city to a double value between 0 and 1. If a cities probability is 1 then a train needs to depart from the city. I have 6 cities that I am working with. Currently I have 6 threads, one for each city, that randomly generates a double and assigns it to the city every second and if a cities probablity changes to 1 a train object departs. The way I am doing it doesnt seem right to me due to the fact that if I had 100 cities I dont want to use a 100 threads.

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: Why do you need multiple threads?

Comment: Also, the probability will never be 1.000

Comment: This is my mistake and I know it. I am using the threads to set the probabilities all at the same time. I dont think i am interpreting the probability part correctly.

Comment: @bp_ltd If you want them set at the same time, why not just use a standard method and set them all at once? You can then create a single thread to act as a "launcher" to simulate the departure of the train. Simply create the thread, pass the trailer identifier, and process from there.

Comment: Thanks Timothy. Just not sure how to do that. Through a for loop?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Maybe you can post the exact wording and anything you have tried already. Right now I don't think I quite understand what you are trying to do or what you are supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend always having only 2 threads.
1. TickChecker
2. ProbabiltyUpdater

TickChecker will iterate through the list and find the city that matches probability to 1 and kicks it off.

ProbabilityUpdater will iterate through the list and updates the probability value periodically. Same interval as the tickChecker or even less than that.

If you want to use on the fly triggering of the probability checker use Observable pattern that way as soon as the probability changes to 1 you kick off your action.

This way you don’t need multiple threads, as everyone in here are saying.
[Observable](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered) reference document.